# How to restart DaemonSet using Fabric8 Java client

Tags: fabric8

It is straightforward to restart a deployment or ReplicatSet using fabric8's K8S Java client. E.g.

```
client.apps().deployments().inNamespace("test")
   .withName("test-deployment")
   .rolling().restart();
```

But I cannot find the "rolling()" method for the daemonSets. E.g. I cannot do something like this:

```
client.apps().daemonSets().inNamespace("test")
    .withName("test-daemon")
    .rolling().restart(); // Won't compile
```

Here is the Maven package I used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I restart a DaemonSet using the Java client API?

Comment: i do not see option for rollout but you can apply update? `DaemonSet daemonSet = client.apps().daemonSets().withName("daemonset-update").edit(c -> new DaemonSetBuilder(c)
        .editSpec().editTemplate().editSpec().editContainer(0)
        .withImage("quay.io/fluentd_elasticsearch/fluentd:v3.0.0")
        .endContainer().endSpec().endTemplate().endSpec()
        .build());`

Comment: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/25eb5874d1d321d10794dd01a29ce9a05e180efa/kubernetes-itests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/DaemonSetIT.java#L51